# How do I add values to a vector when I do not have a subindex specified

Tags: matlab, vector, bezier

I am working on a Bézier curve and this how my code looks right now

```
x=[3 2 6 4 1];
y=[8 1 7 5 9];
n=length(x)-1;
scatter(x,y)
hold on

for t=0:0.01:1
    for i=0:1:n
        xt=nchoosek(n,i)*(t^i)*(1-t)^(n-1)*x(n+1);
        yt=nchoosek(n,i)*(t^i)*(1-t)^(n-1)*y(n+1);
    end
end

plot(xt,yt)
hold off
```

I'm a beginner using Matlab so I'm experiencing some issues. I would like to know how to make xt and yt vectors of the same size as t (that means 101x1) and make the values they get while just i changes be added to the other values as long as t is the same. When t changes, they must start from 0 and add the values they get while just i changes until it gets to n.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The variable `xt` and `yt` should be vectors and their `t`th value updated at each iteration of `i`. Try:

```
x=[3 2 6 4 1];
y=[8 1 7 5 9];
n=length(x)-1;
scatter(x,y)
hold on
T = 0:0.01:1
xt = zeros(size(T));
yt = zeros(size(T));

for idt = 1:length(T)
    t=T(idt);
    for i=0:1:n
        xt(idt)=xt(idt)+nchoosek(n,i)*(t^i)*(1-t)^(n-i)*x(i);
        yt(idt)=yt(idt)+nchoosek(n,i)*(t^i)*(1-t)^(n-i)*y(i);
    end
end

plot(xt,yt)
hold off
```

Comment: What does for t=T exactly mean? Because what I would think is that t begins in 0 and goes all the way to 1 in steps of 0.01. Since t is used as a subindex, I guess that wouldn't be possible

Comment: `T = 0:0.01:1` followed by  `for t=T` is exactly the same as `for t=0:0.01:1`.

Comment: the zeros() calls seem superfluous: it cannot be the case that this procedure leaves "gaps" in either xt or yt. Also you have a `+=` that should be a `+` in the y(t) statement. What does your code actually do differently? (`x(t) = 0 + beziercode` does not seem any different from `x(t) = beziercode`)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the `zeros` serve to preallocate the array. My code implements the description in the last paragraph, where I understand that the `yt(t)` should accumulate the values of `nchoosek...` for `i=0:n`

Comment: I think @JuanDiego is correct: You can't index the arrays with `t` because it's not an integer.

Comment: As a question on correct Bezier curve implementation, I would imagine Juan means to have each dimension `d` modeling the Bezier function `d(t) = Sum[i=0:n] dᵢ·(n choose i)·(1-t)⁽ⁿ⁻ⁱ⁾·tⁱ`, so both x(t) and y(t) are evaluated identically save for the factor from the x/y vectors. But perhaps Juan can say whether or not that's what he needs

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I updated my answer accordig to your feedback. Does it look better so?

Comment: that looks pretty reasonable. If this is true MatLab, though, we can also simplify this by taking advantage of the fact that there is the [bernstein](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/bernstein.html) function, which removes the need for the inner loop.